# UITextField hiding behind keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I followed this tutorial [this tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitextfield-tutorial-handling-keyboard-interactions/)  to avoid text field hiding behind keyboard. The problem lies when I use two views. View1 is calling View2 by pressing next button. both views has textfield and next button to it.  But the problem is this code is working for one view only means

*Case 1*

1. After I start ios simulator view1 loads which has one UITextField and one button
2. I clicked on UITextField, then keyboard pops up and view is scrolable so if textfield is hide behind the keyboard it moves up.
3. Then I press next button so it takes me to view2.
4. Now on view2 I click UITextField then keyboard pops up but text field is behind keyboard and not able to scroll it up.

*Case 2*

1. After I start ios simulator view1 loads which has one UITextField and one button.
2. This time I just pressed Next button without clicking on UITextField. So now I moved to view2
3. In view2 now I pressed UITextField, keyboard pops up and I was able to scroll the textfield up the keyboard.

I dont know why this is happening it should work same for both the views. As given in link I created required files MIBackgroundTapDelegate.h,

```
MIScrollView.h
MIScrollView.m
ScrollableViewController.h
ScrollableViewController.m
```

Comment: making me confused...!! explain in better way..!!

Comment: explain it better way and place a picture of scheme of your views

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question I assume you are having issue of textfields getting covered under keyboard popup. You should put those `UITextFilds` in a `UIScrollView` and call this delegate method. Which will get called on Next/Return button press and it will take your cursor to second `UITextField`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
  NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
  UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];

  if (nextResponder) 
{
    // Found next responder, so set it.
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    txtPswd.secureTextEntry=YES;
    sv.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 150);  //it will push your scrollview 150 pixels upwards.
} 
else 
{
    // Not found, so remove keyboard.
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    sv.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 0);
}
    return NO;
}
```